# Distinguish between generic type that is based on non-generic value type and other generic types in .NET < 4.5

Tags: .net, .net-4.0

For a script that creates controls using reflection, I need to distinguish between

1. Standard value types like `Int32`
2. Generic nullable types that are based on the ones above, like `Int32?`
3. Other generic types like `List<string>`

In .NET 4.5, I can use

```
myType.IsConstructedGenericType
```

in combination with

```
myType.IsValueType
```

and get

1. False/True
2. True/True
3. True/False

However, *IsConstructedGenericType* is not available in earlier .NET versions. How can I accomplish this in .NET 4.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IsGenericType` will do what you want for the examples you've given:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ShowType(typeof(int));
        ShowType(typeof(int?));
        ShowType(typeof(List<string>));
    }

    static void ShowType(Type type)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} / {1}", type.IsGenericType, type.IsValueType);
    }
}
```

The difference is that using [`IsConstructedGenericType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isconstructedgenerictype.aspx) would return false for `typeof(List<>)` whereas [`IsGenericType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isgenerictype.aspx) will return true. You can use [`Type.ContainsGenericParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.containsgenericparameters.aspx) to distinguish between them in .NET 2+... although even that's not *quite* enough, in pathological cases:

```
class Foo<T> : Dictionary<T, string> {}
```

Consider `typeof(Foo<>).BaseType`:

- `IsConstructedGenericType`: True (it contains one assigned type parameter)
- `IsGenericType`: True
- `ContainsGenericParameters`: True (it still contains one unassigned type parameter)

Hopefully this won't be an issue for you.

Comment: Thanks again. Should it get *that* pathological, one should code probably each type that is used explicitly. But I doubt it will be necessary, your initial solution covers all our test cases so far.

Answer (score 4):

You can substitute `.IsGenericType && !.ContainsGenericParameters` for that.

The catch is that this does not detect if any of the generic type arguments is itself an open generic type (for example, in `typeof(List<List<>>)`), so you 'd need to do it recursively using [`GetGenericArguments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx).

This example code should work, although I didn't test it and make no guarantees:

```
public static class TypeExtensions {
    public static bool IsConstructedGenericType(this Type t)
    {
        if (!t.IsGenericType || t.ContainsGenericParameters)
        {
             return false;
        }

        if (!t.GetGenericArguments().All(
             a => !a.IsGenericType || a.IsConstructedGenericType()))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

The documentation for [`IsGenericType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isgenerictype.aspx) provides very useful information on this matter.

Comment: It works, and it's cool to have a method that replaces IsConstructedGenericType! +1, but the solution of your namesake is shorter.

Comment: @Olaf: The two solutions do not do the same thing, so that's not surprising.